# intellisense not working when property name for interface has underscore

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I had an interface with properties in **snake_case**. Now I want the intellisense to work in visual studio code but however, it seems that those property names with an underscore are not being loaded on the intellisense drop down. see image below [image]

Now I tried changing the format to **camelCase** and it listed all the properties.

[image]

Could this be a bug? It would be better if snake_case properties would work with intellisense as our team have already used that format for the entire project.

**UPDATE**

I created a project from scratch and the results are the same. Here are some screenshots.

with *snake_case* properties
[image]

with *camelCase* properties
[image]

the ts file.
[image]

My visual studio code version is **1.23.1**

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue with just the code in the screen shot, created a file with the comment interface, imported it in another file, all memebers show up

Comment: i tried creating this from scratch just now and it is still the same. Intellisense works on ts files but on html pages with angular bindings and interpolation it wont load those properties with underscore.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir see my latest update on question. The results are still the same

Comment: do you have any plugins/extensions that might be interfering?

Comment: @SurajRao no. i created an angular project from scratch and it still the same.